# Do I need to persist a prepared statement?

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have the following code:

```
public function getDefinitions($wordID) {
    $query = $this->dbc->prepare('SELECT * FROM definitions WHERE wordID = ?');

    $query->bind_param('i', $wordID);
    $query->execute();

    // ...

    $query->close();

    return $result;
}
```

It would seem that this would recreate the [prepared statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for each invocation. That does not seem to take advantage of the full benefit of prepared statements. Especially in the case these prepare statements were [stored server side](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). Is that true?

If so, should I store the prepare statement (in this case as a property) to persist it between invocations. Is there a way to persist the prepared statement between requests? I assume that's essentially a stored procedure?

Currently I am using MySQLi. Please note any API difference if I were using another driver (e.g. PDO).

Comment: I would say persisting the $query would make a lot of sense, otherwise you gain no benefit from using a prepared statement, especially if you know you are going to call it many times within the same execution of a single script.

Comment: You do gain one benefit still, which is the use of bind variables; but a simple approach to persisting the prepared statement might be to make $query a static

Comment: other than placeholders/parameters, the only time prepared statements really should be used is if you're going to use the SAME query over and over. the extra overhead to prepare a one-shot query is definitely "useless". but proper use of placeholders to prevent sql injection attacks massively outweighs that overhead.

Comment: @Marc B, understood. Is there an alternative to prepared statements but still provides the placeholder benefit?

Comment: nope. for placeholders you have to prepare. at least with mysqli you can use the `?` anonymous params and pass in an array of values to fill in, without having to `bind()` each one individually.

Comment: Deleting previous comment, a your question can be understood in two ways. Speaking of prepared statements in general, "placeholder benefit" IS a prepared statement, its cornerstone and essence. So, generally speaking, "placeholder benefit without prepared statement" is a mere oxymoron.

Comment: On the other hand, speaking of the **native** prepared statements, surely there is an alternative called "emulated prepared statement" which utilizes the idea of placeholder without two-trip preparations. And it is implemented in a number of libraries, starting from PDO.

Comment: @Your Common Sense, thanks for the clarification. Nonetheless, I will look at the [safemysql PHP class](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql).

Answer (score 7):

> should I store the prepare statement (in this case as a property) to persist it between invocations.

I wouldn't say you "should". You may, if you foresee a lot of consequent invocations (which you cannot group up to call at once). Either way, you scarcely will be able to notice the real life difference.

> Is there a way to persist the prepared statement between requests?

In PHP - no. Prepared statements are connection-based, connection is closed along with request, and persistent connections won't help you either, as [mysqli is using designated mechanism](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-change-user.html) to clean connection state before reuse.

> Please note any API difference if I were using another driver (e.g. PDO).

PDO has an advantage over mysqli as it can *emulate* prepared statements, eliminating even such a negligible overhead of two database calls, which makes it more suitable for the real life usage (beside other key benefits).

In a nutshell, the "prepare once-multiple execute" feature of native prepared statements can have noticeable effect only for a huge number of queries, starting from thousands.

Comment: +1 for thoroughness. A quick followup - instead of *should* would you consider it *best practice* for such a DAO class to store a prepare statement in a class variable - regardless of the performance difference?

Comment: I wouldn't advise so. It seems to me that keeping every prepared statement open,  you'll end up with dozens (or even hundreds) statement objects hanging around till the script termination on the PHP side and the same mess on the mysql side as well, while only very small number of them got actually reused. I'd rather make this feature optional.

Comment: Fair. Just seems that I'm not getting the full advantage (however negligible) of prepare statements if I'm generating it for every method call.

Answer (score 1):

You should persist the query if you plan on using it again.

As you are using mysqli prepared statements should always be real prepared statements. (In contradiction to PDO, which emulates queries based on the used driver and might not send an additional database call).  The data replacing the placeholders is then sent in a different pack of data. 
A nativly-prepared statement takes therefore two trips to the database if only issued once.
Sending this extra action takes time. If you know that you only want to issue the query once, it might in certain circumstances be positive to use traditional queries. (However, this can only be advisable if you are **absolutly sure about the potential negative security implications** standard queries have in comparison to prepared statements. The **added level safety using prepared statements outwights the benefit such a change** may have in most cases.)

However, if you want to re-run the query preparing it is the right approach. [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/statement-caching.html) is supposed to cache converted statements, so the php-site is the only way of optimizing and reusing.

What you can do is to prevent the additional call to the prepare method and the action it may trigger in the  low-level database connector by preserving the statement in the method using a static variable or a property. The impact on *most* real applications is however arguable.

Comment: -1 for the "don't use prepared statements" alone. "if you can safely escape the data" is too presuming and uncertain statement to be advised for anyone. In a real world, if you take an average PHP user, for your life you won't make him tell you, what "safe escaping" is.

Comment: I suggest re-wording the part mentioned by @YourCommonSense, in which case your answer is good. It'd be a waste to downvote you based on the mentioned fact seeing the rest of the answer is well constructed and solid.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I hope that the change improves the answer. If it is still to open I'm going to remove that part to maje the answer better.

Comment: Well, I'll take back my downvote but please read [this my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23126179/285587) regarding this matter of  "absolute assurance"